# Is there a good date parser for Java?

Tags: java, date, parsing

Does anyone know a good date parser for different languages/locales. The built-in parser of Java (SimpleDateFormat) is very strict. It should complete missing parts with the current date.

For example

- if I do not enter the year (only day and month) then the current year should be used.
- if the year is 08 then it should not parse 0008 because the current year pattern has 4 digits.

Edit: I want to parse the input from a user. For example if the locale date format of the user is "dd.mm.yyyy" and the user type only "12.11." then the parser should accept this as a valid date with the value "12.11.2008". The target is a good usability.

Comment: "It should complete missing parts with the current date."  And it *should* give me a Bentley.  I'm not sure "should" is appropriate here.  Can you rephrase this to say what you want, not what someone else should do?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 23):

Check Joda Time, and its Freaky [Formatters](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Input_and_Output).

[Java 8 includes JSR-310](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) so that could be a solution as well.

Comment: I love Joda Time. It's so good, it'll be the basis of a rewrite of Date Time handling in Java 7

Comment: So, how would the code to answer this question would look like using Joda Time?

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 14):

From [43642](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842/how-would-you-programmatically-create-a-pattern-from-a-date-that-is-stored-in-a), although not necessarily a duplicate:

See Apache Commons' [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). There's a `parseDate` method that takes your `String` and multiple patterns to try and spits out a `Date` instance.

Comment: +1 for apache Commons!  Those libraries are so often overlooked or underappreciated and many programmers really don't know what they include.

Comment: Apache Commons in general are great. But Joda Time is marvelous! :)

Comment: The `DateUtils` functionality is now outmoded, supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 8):

(Edited for clarity.)

Personally, I think strict is good. So many different situations call for different rules around relaxed parsing, it's impossible to really put that into a common library comprehensively.

However, I *would* thoroughly recommend [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of the built-in date/time classes in general. Their formatters and parsers are thread-safe and immutable, which helps too. Joda Time has some support for relaxed parsing, as shown in the other answer, but you should expect to have to provide some of the rules yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I would say [JChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic) if you're looking for something that will parse dates from natural "fuzzy" human input.

I've used both JChronic and Chronic (the original Ruby version) with great success.

Comment: I have emailed the author to ask if he wants me to host it on my website

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

[`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder::parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,long))

## java.time

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class parses strings into date-time objects.

You can create customized instances of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) by using the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class. That builder class enables you to specify default values for missing components of the input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter f =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern( "MM-dd" )
                .parseDefaulting(
                        ChronoField.YEAR ,
                        ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).getYear()
                )
                .toFormatter() ;

String input = "01-23" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;

System.out.println( ld ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-01-23

See also [*DateTimeFormatterBuilder with specified parseDefaulting conflicts for YEAR field*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38307816/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The POJava project on SourceForge has a DateTime object that parses dates from multiple languages (when month is specified as a name) and is configurable between MM-DD-YYYY and DD-MM-YYYY.  It parses dates heuristically, picking out the most likely year, month, date, hour, minute, second, and time zone rather than supporting predefined formats.  The jar file is about 60K in size.

There is ambiguity in interpretation of a date like "10-08" in that it could be intended as shorthand for either "2008-10-08" or "Oct 2008".  You could append the year yourself if you are accepting the sort of shorthand you give in your example.

Proj: [POJava](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=226950)
Docs: [HOWTO use DateTime](http://pojava.org/examples/datetime.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Your first requirement** has been [answered by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498871/10819573).

> - if I do not enter the year (only day and month) then the current year should be used.
> - if the year is 08 then it should not parse 0008 because the current year pattern has 4 digits.

`DateTimeFormatter` allows us to specify the optional patterns inside square brackets. For the second requirement, you can specify the optional pattern, `[.[uuuu][uu]]` while building the `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace JVM's ZoneId, ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable one e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")
        int defaultYear = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getYear();

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("dd.MM[.[uuuu][uu]]")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, defaultYear)
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "12.11",
                    "12.11.21",
                    "12.11.2021"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(s, dtf)));        
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-11-12
2021-11-12
2021-11-12
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8wnpJ2)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use DateFormat ... Current standard until the welcome respite of Joda.

Answer (score 1):

[Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is usually the way to go, but understand that most Java Date management will be handled on your part if you want it done properly.  [Timezone](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) is a good thing to look into if you have to manage international/cross-zone info. [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is also a neat thing and is the inspiration behind the new suggested Date/Time concepts to be added to Java in [JSR 310](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/18/jsr-310-new-java-date-time-api.html).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: FYI, JSR 310 is *not* JodaTime although it is inspired by it and the spec lead is the author of JT.

Comment: thanks for the comment... my mistake, will correct my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement an extensible PHP's `strtotime` in Java [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268174/phps-strtotime-in-java/1268380#1268380)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say +1 for JodaTime. In addition to parsing, Joda makes just about every date-related operation better.