# Matching algorithm or regular expression?

Tags: regex, algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a huge log file with different types of string rows, and I need to extract data in a "smart" way from these.

Sample snippet:

```
2011-03-05 node32_three INFO stack trace, at empty string asfa 11120023
--- - MON 23 02 2011 ERROR stack trace NONE
```

For instance, what is the best way to extract the date from each row, independent of date format?

Comment: Do you mean 'extract the dates' ? because your example has two dates.

Comment: do I understand correctly that your huge log file contains different types of rows in which date may appear in different formats? If this is the case, then regex may not be a good solution.

Comment: @heykalrm: I edited your question to show individual lines in your example, but I'm not sure I got it right. Please check it and verify that the line split is in the correct place.

Comment: @MarcoS Yes, the dates may appear in different formats. If not regex, what's your solution?

Comment: I gave an answer with an alternative approach: use regex to separate date stings and Joda time to parse them. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a regex for different formats like so:

```
 (fmt1)|(fmt2)|....
```

Where *fmt1*, *fmt2* etc are the individual regexes, for yor example

```
(20\d\d-[01]\d-[0123]\d)|((?MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN) [0123]\d [01]\d 20\d\d)
```

Note that to prevent the chance to match arbitrary numbers I restricted year, month and day numbers accordingly. For example, a day number cannot start with 4, neither can a month number start with 2.

This gives the following pseudo code:

```
// remember that you need to double each backslash when writing the
// pattern in string form
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("...");    // compile once and for all
String s;
for each line 
    s = current input line;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        String d = m.group();    // d is the string that matched
        ....
    }
```

Each individual date pattern is written in () to make it possible to find out what format we had, like so:

```
        int fmt = 0;
        // each (fmt) is a group, numbered starting with 1 from left to right
        for (int i = 1; fmt == 0 && i <= total number of different formats; i++) 
            if (m.group(i) != null) fmt = i;
```

For this to work, inner (regex) groups must be written (?regex) so that they do not count as capture-groups, look at updated example.

Comment: Great! Do you possibly have some Java implementation example for your regexes above?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java, you may want to have a look at [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Also, read this [question and related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222245/is-there-a-good-date-parser-for-java). I think Joda [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) should give you all the flexibility that you need to parse the various date/time format of your log file.

A quick example:

```
String dateString = "2011-04-18 10:41:33";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

Just define a `String[]` for the formats of you date/time, and pass each element to `DateTimeFormat` to get the corresponding `DateTimeFormatter`. You can use regex just separate date strings from other stuff in the log lines, and then you can use the various `DateTimeFormatter`s to try and parse them.