# java smart date parser

Tags: java, parsing, date

is there a smart date parser in Java that would parse a variety of date formats without knowning ahead what the format is?
for example I can have the following formats:

```
21-3-1998,
March 2004, 2001, 
3/4/97
12-Dec-1998
```

is there a simple parse call(third party lib is ok) I can use to handle them call?

Comment: In my experience, whenever we've tried to enumerate all reasonable date formats, we soon discovered that there was yet another format someone was using that we hadn't considered.

Comment: When you see date 3/4/2011, do you expect your smart parser to parse it as March 4, 2011 or April 3, 2011?

Comment: This is the reason not to use this stupid `xx/xx/yyyy` format. The ISO 8601 formats were invented for a reason. (Does not help for someone who has to parse this, though.)

Comment: So what really is `March 2004, 2001,`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse any date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a good out-of-the-box choice, given almost unlimited number of permutations; but if I had to do it, I'd start with de-facto Java date package, [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), and just do linear lookup with sequence of allowed data formats, and accept first one that parses succsefully.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Is there a good date parser for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222245/is-there-a-good-date-parser-for-java)

for some suggestions. (Apache Commons and Joda Time)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the standard Java solution of `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)`?

As per [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29):

> Parses text from a string to produce a
>   Date. The method attempts to parse
>   text starting at the index given by
>   pos. If parsing succeeds, then the
>   index of pos is updated to the index
>   after the last character used (parsing
>   does not necessarily use all
>   characters up to the end of the
>   string), and the parsed date is
>   returned. The updated pos can be used
>   to indicate the starting point for the
>   next call to this method. If an error
>   occurs, then the index of pos is not
>   changed, the error index of pos is set
>   to the index of the character where
>   the error occurred, and null is
>   returned.