# Getting time from String

Tags: java, string, parsing, time

My Java code must get string "HH:MM" from console and needs to operate with it.
is there possible to parse such time from string in order to add, for example,2 hours.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.print("Enter some time:");
String enteredTime = in.readLine(); 
// here I want to get time in some variable
```

Thanks!

As result I have to get three dates and define is there three date between another dates .
I understand that I can split string on parts and work with their, but I'm lloking for simple way to operate with such times.

I found good solution:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date ten = parser.parse("10:00");
Date eighteen = parser.parse("18:00");

try {
    Date userDate = parser.parse(someOtherDate);
    if (userDate.after(ten) && userDate.before(eighteen)) {
    ...
}
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Invalid date was entered
}
```

Comment: String#split(":") can work well here. Check out the String API for more on this.

Comment: what have you tried? Three things that pop into my head at least are java.text.DateFormat, java.text.SimpleDateFormat and, java.util.Date...

Comment: I need to get three times and define is there third date between another dates.

Comment: Try [a good date parser.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222245/is-there-a-good-date-parser-for-java

Comment: Dates or times? Those are two different things.

Comment: Times, pardon - it was mistake

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm");
sdf.parse ("13:47");
```

Comment: be warned that this will give you "Thu Jan 01 13:47:00 1970"!

Comment: It's normal, I need to calculate only times, date can be any

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to do some date arithmetics like adding durations to dates. Then you should definitely use [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of java.util.Date and Calendar.

Joda gives you Period and Duration entities and a nice and readeable API.

Comment: Thanks, I know about Joda , but unfortunally, I can't use any API apart Java.